# Jquery ScratchOut effect

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas, jquery-easing

I am searching for the scratchOut effect, call it whatever you like.

Its the effect of an image being erased from the foreground so the background image becomes visible.

I have tried to recreate this effect using a jquery plugin but its simply not as smooth as i would like it to be.

Does anyone have this effect or has already recreated or seen this somewhere?

Example in comment, it is not perfect yet, but you get the idea if you look at it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nytrm/LCTx5/21/

Comment: Please explain why this example is not enough for you. What do you want the effect to look like exactly ( got an example without html5 canvas ? ), and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I just spent a day trying out a few and this one: http://www.catchmyfame.com/2011/06/28/a-jquery-canvas-scratch-off/ ... has is the only one where if you scroll OUTSIDE of the window pane, it doesnt select all the text on the website. I.e. It's the best one.

Comment: p.s. it requires a commercial license if used for profit. I've asked what that cost is and will post it here if I get a reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a few plugins.

They all work with mousedown to scratch the image, otherwise I think they are close what you are looking for. It shouldn't be very hard to change to mousedown behavior and make it loop automatically.

http://rabidflash.com/authoring/codecanyon/scratch/

http://www.senamion.com/blog/2010/03/30/jquery-jscratchcard-scratchcard-effect-on-image/

http://www.htmldrive.net/items/demo/880/Images-Scratch-Card-Plugin-jQuery-Scratchie

Comment: All the links in this answer are now dead, and going to spam sites.

Suggest updating to:

https://codecanyon.net/item/wp-scratchit/10080179
https://www.cssscript.com/scratch-ticket-javascript-canvas/